# Converting numbers to 2 digits float number in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follow:

```
Names   Cider   Juice   Subtotal (Cider)   Subtotal (Juice) Total
Richard   13        9           $ 71.5            $ 40.5  $ 112.0
George     7       21           $ 38.5            $ 94.5  $ 133.0
Paul       0       23           $ 0.0            $ 103.5  $ 103.5
John      22        5           $ 121.0           $ 22.5  $ 143.5
Total     42       58           $ 231.0          $ 261.0  $ 492.0
Average 10.5     14.5           $ 57.75          $ 65.25  $ 123.0
```

I'd like to all float numbers to be '.2f' (2 digits float) numbers. `.applymap()` does not work since I have string type in "Names" column. Is there a work around using `.applymap()` or is there a better way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Names", "Cider", "Juice", "Subtotal(Cider)", "Subtotal(Juice)", "Total"])
people_ordered = input('How many people ordered? ')  # type str

# Create the 4x3 table from user input
for i in range(int(people_ordered)):
    names = input("Enter the name of Person #{}: ".format(i+1))  # type str

    cider_orderred = float(input("How many orders of cider did {} have? ".format(names)))  # type str -> int
    #cider_orderred = float("{:.2f}".format(cider_orderred))
    juice_orderred = float(input("How many orders of juice did {} have? ".format(names)))  # type str -> int
    #juice_orderred = float("{:.2f}".format(juice_orderred))

    # store the values of the subtotals from user inputs
    cider_sub = 5.50 * cider_orderred  # type float
    cider_sub = float("{:.2f}".format(cider_sub))
    juice_sub = 4.50 * juice_orderred  # type float
    juice_sub = float("{:.2f}".format(juice_sub))
    total = cider_sub + juice_sub  # type float
    total = float("{:.2f}".format(total))

    # create the 4x6 table
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[[names, int(cider_orderred), int(juice_orderred), round(cider_sub, 2), round(juice_sub, 2), round(total, 2)]],
        columns=["Names", "Cider", "Juice", "Subtotal(Cider)", "Subtotal(Juice)", "Total"])

    # merge the the 4x3 into the 4x6 table
    df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=0)

# add rows of "Total" and "Average"
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
df.loc['Average'] = df[:int(people_ordered)].mean()

# Adding "$" to the prices
df['Subtotal(Cider)'] = '$ ' + df['Subtotal(Cider)'].astype(str)
df['Subtotal(Juice)'] = '$ ' + df['Subtotal(Juice)'].astype(str)
df['Total'] = '$ ' + df['Total'].astype(str)

# Set the row name to "Total" and "Average"
df.iloc[int(people_ordered),0] = 'Total'
df.iloc[int(people_ordered)+1,0] = 'Average'

# Set the index according to 'Names'
df.index = range(len(df.index))
df.set_index('Names', inplace=True)


print(df)
```

updated with my current solution as above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for only numeric columns
- [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `$` with one or more whitespaces `\s+`
- convert to `float`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
- convert to custom format by [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

---

```
df = (df.set_index('Names')
        .replace('\$\s+','', regex=True)
        .astype(float)
        .applymap('{:,.2f}'.format))
print (df)
         Cider  Juice Subtotal (Cider) Subtotal (Juice)   Total
Names                                                          
Richard  13.00   9.00            71.50            40.50  112.00
George    7.00  21.00            38.50            94.50  133.00
Paul      0.00  23.00             0.00           103.50  103.50
John     22.00   5.00           121.00            22.50  143.50
Total    42.00  58.00           231.00           261.00  492.00
Average  10.50  14.50            57.75            65.25  123.00
```

EDIT:

I try improve your solution:

```
people_ordered = input('How many people ordered? ') 

Data = []
# Create the 4x3 table from user input
for i in range(int(people_ordered)):
    names = input("Enter the name of Person #{}: ".format(i+1))  # type str

    cider_orderred = int(input("How many orders of cider did {} have? ".format(names)))  # type str -> int
    juice_orderred = int(input("How many orders of juice did {} have? ".format(names)))  # type str -> int

    #create in loop tuple and append to list Data
    Data.append((names, cider_orderred, juice_orderred))

#create DataFrame form list of tuples, create index by Names
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['Names','Cider','Juice']).set_index('Names')

#count all new columns, rows
df1['Subtotal(Cider)'] = df1['Cider'] * 5.5
df1['Subtotal(Juice)'] = df1['Juice'] * 4.5
df1['Total'] = df1['Subtotal(Cider)'] + df1['Subtotal(Juice)']
df1.loc['Total'] = df1.sum()
#remove row Total for correct mean
df1.loc['Average'] = df1.drop('Total').mean()

#get custom format of columns in list cols
cols = ['Subtotal(Cider)','Subtotal(Juice)','Total']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].applymap('$ {:,.2f}'.format)
#create column from index
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df1)
     Names  Cider  Juice Subtotal(Cider) Subtotal(Juice)     Total
0        r   13.0    9.0         $ 71.50         $ 40.50  $ 112.00
1        g    7.0   21.0         $ 38.50         $ 94.50  $ 133.00
2        p    0.0   23.0          $ 0.00        $ 103.50  $ 103.50
3        j   22.0    5.0        $ 121.00         $ 22.50  $ 143.50
4    Total   42.0   58.0        $ 231.00        $ 261.00  $ 492.00
5  Average   10.5   14.5         $ 57.75         $ 65.25  $ 123.00
```

Comment: So to end need `.reset_index()` for column from `index`. How many columns are in real? Only 2 categories?

Comment: @jezrael Take your time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jezrael I need the final output as the table, looking exactly like the table I attached. I will need to ask for a number of people who ordered, a list of names, numbers of apple cider orders, and numbers of apple juice from user input. If there are ways to do it with list, that's ok too.

Comment: @jezrael I agree. It should be int. Somehow, my result in Average row showing NaN, for "Cider" and "Juice" columns. I changed here and there, it'd be fine. It's showing NaN again...I have no idea why...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166943/discussion-between-meruemu-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Meruemu - So I edit answer. First there is problem with int columns, because `mean` row convert all values to `float`s, if need something explain, let me know.

Comment: @jezrael I need some time to digest, but it looks fantastic.

Answer (score 5):

**Just set all floats to 2 digits in general**

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format
```

Although:  df['column'].sum()  will not become 2 digits...?

Comment: Did you find a solution for .sum()? Thanks!

Comment: also math.fsum() should work with lists but couldn't get this working with pandas..   use of.. from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport. using this data for the results can help also..

Comment: To make answer a bit more complete; 
df.describe() - will be 2 digits result of sum (count row)

df_sums = df.describe()
print(df_sums.loc['count']['sum column']) - can become more or less digits

If float is (x.00) it print result is (x.0) or will give you a complete float e.g. if column result of df.describe() = (x.05) can become in print result (x.04673248593)

type() is <class 'numpy.float64'>

Answer (score 4):

if you want to apply to particular column you can try

```
col_name
 123.1
 456

df["col_name"] = df["col_name"].apply(lambda x: format(float(x),".2f"))

**after applying format**

col_name
123.10
456.00
```